# Why does this infinite Loop converge?

Tags: java, math

Why does this code in Java output the value `-210`, when it's an infinite Loop?

Does this loop end when the integer reaches its max value?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a=100;
    int b=110;
    int c=0;
    while(a>=100 && b<=110) {
        a=a+1;
        b=b-1;
        c=a-b;
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This loop terminates due to integer overflow. When `a` reaches the max value of int, incrementing it makes it negative. When `b` reaches the min value of int, decrementing it makes it a large positive. Once one of them overflows, the loop terminates.

Due to the initial values, `a` would overflow first, since both are initialized to positive values, so `a` is closer to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` than `b` is to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

As to why the output it `-210` :

`a` is incremented `(Integer.MAX_VALUE-100)+1` times until the loop terminates
`b` is decremented the same number of times.

The final `a` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (due to overflow)
The final `b` is `110 - ((Integer.MAX_VALUE-100)+1) = 
            110 - ((-Integer.MIN_VALUE-1-100)+1) = 
            Integer.MIN_VALUE + 210`

Hence, `a-b` ends up being `Integer.MIN_VALUE - (Integer.MIN_VALUE + 210) = -210`

Answer (score 3):

Let me add to Eran's answer.

The variable a will wrap around when it reaches INT_MAX, and so does b when it reaches the negative of INT_MAX.

Which one reaches the limit first?  a will.

Then the condition on a>=100 will fail, so the loop will finish.

At the time the loop finishes, the value of b will be 110 - (INT_MAX - 100).

Thus, c = a - b = -INT_MAX - ( 110 - (INT_MAX - 100) ) = 210;

Comment: Thank you, I need to calculate this by hand at uni, so it's very useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what happens. Once a goes beyond the max value, the while condition is no longer true.

if you were to do something like this:

```
int a = 2147483647;
a = a + 1;
```

and you print out a, it would show you value of -2147483648.

Link to [Java integer operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)